# Problem tryinng to launch a Visualforce page from a quick action in the Account layout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, quickaction

I'm trying to lunch this VF page from an Object (Account) Quick Action but the Action is not showing in the layout so I´m not able to see the page.

**editCases.vf**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"
           extensions="AccountsController"
           sidebar="false" tabStyle="Account" >
    
    <style>
        .dataCell input {
        width:100px;
        }
    </style>
    
    <apex:form >
        
        <apex:actionFunction status="outStatus"
                             name="yacks" rerender="table" />
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Cases"
                        mode="edit" id="table">
            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                
                
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}"
                                    value=" Save " />
                
                <apex:commandButton action="{!add}"
                                    value="Add"
                                    rerender="table" />
                
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            
            <apex:pageMessages />    
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection
                                   title="Account Name : {!Account.name} "
                                   columns="1">
                
                <apex:pageBlockTable
                                     value="{!caseItems}"
                                     var="item"  >
                    
                    <apex:column
                                 headerValue="Action">
                        
                        <apex:commandLink
                                          value="Del"
                                          action="{!del}"
                                          rerender="table" >
                            
                            <apex:param
                                        name="delname"
                                        value="{!item.CaseNumber}" />
                            
                        </apex:commandLink>
                        
                    </apex:column>
                    
                    <apex:column
                                 headerValue="Case Number">
                        
                        <a href="/{!item.CaseNumber}">
                            {!item.CaseNumber}</a>
                        
                        <apex:outputPanel
                                          rendered="{!isnull(item.CaseNumber)}" >
                            
                            <apex:inputField
                                             required="true"
                                             value="{!item.CaseNumber}"
                                             onchange="yacks();" />
                            
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        
                    </apex:column>
                    
                    <apex:column
                                 headerValue="Subject">
                        
                        <apex:inputField
                                         required="true"
                                         value="{!item.Subject}"
                                         onchange="yacks();"/>
                        
                    </apex:column>
                    
                    <apex:column
                                 headerValue="Reason" >
                        
                        <apex:inputField
                                         required="true"
                                         value="{!item.Reason}"
                                         onchange="yacks();" />
                        
                    </apex:column>
                    
                    <apex:column
                                 headerValue="Origin" >
                        
                        <apex:inputField
                                         value="{!item.Origin}"
                                         onchange="yacks();"/>
                        
                    </apex:column>
                    
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            
        </apex:pageBlock>
        
    </apex:form>
    
</apex:page>
```

**AccountController.apxc**

```
public with sharing class AccountsController {
    
    /* I set the Account and Case Objects
    here for use through out the code*/
    
    public Account acct { get; private set;}
    public Case[] caseItems { get; private set; }
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    
    // constructor, loads the Account and
    // any cases associated with it
    
    void caseItems(id id) {
        acct = [SELECT Id, Name, Type, AccountNumber, Site,
                (SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Status, Reason,Origin,
                 Subject FROM Cases) FROM Account
                where id = :id limit 1];
        //Hook caseItems to the query above
        caseItems = acct.Cases;
    }
    
    //Define the id
    id accountid;
    
    /* A List Method to delete the Cases assigned*/
    public List<Case> todelete = new List<Case>();
    
    public AccountsController (ApexPages.StandardController c)
    {
        /* this will kickoff you main page */
        controller = c;
        /* to get this current Account Id*/
        accountid = c.getRecord().id;
        /*kick off the init() function*/
        init();
    }
    
    public AccountsController () {
        accountid =
            ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        
        init();
        
    }
    
    void init() {
                /* load up Cases
                    basically we defined caseitems up on top, so
                    when the page loads then caseItems(accountId)
                    will go through the query and list out the
                    Items assoicated with it */
        caseItems(accountid);  
    }
    
    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            upsert caseItems;
            if ( todelete.size() > 0 ) {           
                delete todelete;   
            }
            caseItems(acct.id);
        }
        catch ( DmlException exc) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(exc);
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    
    /* your Delete functionality*/
    public PageReference del() {
        
        string delname = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('delname');
        system.assert( delname != null );
        integer gone = -1;
        integer i = 0;
        
        for ( i=0; i< caseItems.size(); i++ ) {
            if (caseItems[i].CaseNumber== delname) {
                gone = i;
            }
        }
        if ( gone >= 0) {
            todelete.add(caseItems.remove(gone) );
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public PageReference add() {
        // insert a new line, after user clicks Add
        Case cs =  new Case(
            AccountId = acct.id,
            Subject = 'hello', Status = 'Low',
            Reason = 'Other',Origin='Low'
        );
        caseItems.add ( cs );
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've created the Quick Action in the Account Object:

[image]

and then added the Quick Action (Call VF) to the Account Layout but the Action is not showing :/

[image]

Account Layout where the action should appear for launching the VF page

[image]

Any idea why this could be happening ?
Thanks a lot for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the quick action visible in Lightning, you'll also need to add it to "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions".

Adding some screenshots to make it easier for you

[image]

As you can see in the above image, I added this button under the Lightning actions.

[image]

And then it's available under actions on the Account lightning page.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that one ... I tried to add it to the lightning area but it wasn´t letting me, then I realized how it was made, thanks a lot for the answer